# Check if HTML element has specific grandchild element

Tags: javascript

How can I check if an element is a grandchild of a specific element? I thought we could use `contains` method on the on the grandparent element after getting all of its descendants?

```js
let grandparent = document.getElementById("grandparent");
let childs = document.getElementsByClassName("child")

for(let i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
  let test = grandparent.getElementsByTagName("*")
  if (test.contains(childs[i])) { 
    console.log(true) 
  } else {
    console.log(false)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="grandparent">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
```

Comment: `childs[i].parentNode.parentNode === grandparent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like by making use of [parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement):

```js
let grandparent = document.getElementById("grandparent");
let childs = document.getElementsByClassName("child")

for(let i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
  if (childs[i].parentElement.parentElement === grandparent) { 
    console.log(true) 
  } else {
    console.log(false)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="grandparent">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `.closest('#grandparent');` or to get it from the parent a selector like `let child = document.querySelector('#grandparent #parent .child');` or `querySelectorAll` if you wanted all the `.child` elements

Or you could use the `parentElement` or `parentNode` properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the parent node with a loop

```js
let grandparent = document.getElementById("grandparent");
let childs = document.getElementsByClassName("child")

for (let i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
  let p = childs[i];

  let found = false;

  // iterate until a prent element same as grandparent 
  // or until it reaching the root element
  while (p = p.parentNode) {
    // if found set found as true and break the loop
    if (p === grandparent) {
      found = true;
      break
    }
  }
  
  if (found) {
    console.log(true)
  } else {
    console.log(false)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="grandparent">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
```